# Set selected value of second select based on specific values chosen from first select

Tags: jquery

I've got a JQuery problem that I can't seem to get my head around - I have a SELECT that, depending on the user's choice, needs to set the selected value of a related select to a particular value.

For example:

```
SELECT A OPTIONS
box
wheel
rabbit
```

In pseudocode, it would go something like "IF SELECT A SELECTED VALUE ONCHANGE is "rabbit", SET SELECT B SELECTED VALUE to "hutch" OR IF SELECT A SELECTED VALUE ONCHANGE is "box", SET SELECT B SELECTED VALUE to "container"

I know once I see the solution I'll kick myself, but I've been braindead about this for a few days now... any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just as a note, you can mark an answer accepted by clicking the checkmark near the voting area.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this might work

```
var map = {
  "rabbit": "hutch", 
  "box": "container"
};

$("#a").change(function() {
  var newVal = map[$(this).val()];
  if (newVal) $("#b").val(newVal);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// create a map of values to map between:
var mapping = {
  'rabbit' : 'hutch',
  'box' : 'container'
};

// on change set the other select value accordingly.
$('#Select1').change(function() {
  $('#Select2').val(mapping[$(this).val()]);
});
```

Comment: +1 for being a line shorter ;)  -- Although I put in the `if (newVal)` so it would be pretty easy to `else` and do something like hide/clear the value

Comment: Wow - you guys are great - the solution worked perfectly, even with my dynamically-created fieldsets! Thanks to everyone else who contributed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something or would this do it?

```
if ($('#selectA').val() == 'rabbit') {
  $('#selectB').val('hutch');
}
```